# С# Mega.nz | Скачивание файла с progress bar'ом

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу сделать скачивание файла с Mega.nz с прогресс баром. Я могу скачать файл, но как добавить прогресс бар... Ничего не понимаю.
Вот API https://gpailler.github.io/MegaApiClient/articles/faq.html

Comment: Там по ссылке есть пример How can I retrieve progression during download/upload. Вместо вывода на консоль меняйте значение у прогрессбара.

Comment: @PashaPash Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "double" в "int".

Comment: преобразуйте явно - `(int)x`

Comment: Теперь нужно избавится от зависания, когда на кнопку нажимаешь

Comment: @Hiteke, чтобы от него избавиться, нужно увидеть Ваш код. Вероятно, вы используете синхронные версии методов.

Answer (score 2):

Обновлять прогресс можно так, как показано в примере кода.

`_progressBar.Maximum = 1000;` и `(int)(value * 10d);` могут быть заменены на `_progressBar.Maximum = 100;` и `(int)(value);`

Можно использовать стандартный дотнетовский `Progress<T>` класс. Я написал свой, так как не знал о его существовании, подсказали в комментариях.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace FileDownloader
{
    public class Progress : IProgress<double>
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;

        public event EventHandler<double> ProgressUpdated;

        public Progress()
        {
            _synchronizationContext = 
                SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
        }

        public void Report(double value)
        {
            _synchronizationContext.Post(state =>
            {
                ProgressUpdated?.Invoke(this, value);
            }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CG.Web.MegaApiClient;

namespace FileDownloader
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        // ...
        private readonly Progress _progress;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // ...
            _progress = new Progress();
            _progress.ProgressUpdated += OnProgressUpdated;

            _progressBar.Minimum = 0;
            _progressBar.Maximum = 1000;
        }

        private void OnProgressUpdated(object sender, double value)
        {
            updateProgress(value);
        }

        private async void DownloadButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Лучше добавить ещё код вида: 
            // если скачивание запущено, то выйти из метода.
            // Этот код нужно добавить, даже если кнопка 
            // выключается на время скачивания.
            // А то иногда мелькают вопросы: "как сделать
            // неактивную кнопку активной?"
            // ...

            await _client.LoginAnonymousAsync();

            // ...

            try
            {
                await client.DownloadFileAsync(fileLink, node.Name, _progress/*, _cancellation.Token*/);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                updateProgress(0d);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // ...
            }
        }

        private void updateProgress(double value)
        {
            _percentageLabel.Text = ((int)value).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "%";
            _progressBar.Value = (int)(value * 10d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как-то неправильно вы `IProgress` используете. Все равно приходится делать проверку `InvokeRequired` и юзать `Invoke`. Правильно так: создаёте экземпляр класса `Progress` и его передаёте.

Comment: @CasperSC [Any handler provided to the constructor or event handlers registered with the ProgressChanged event *are invoked through a SynchronizationContext instance captured when the instance is constructed*.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @PashaPash, всё, понял про что писал Alexander Petrov. Не приходилось мне этот класс использовать. Написал свой такой же в итоге.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, всё, я понял о чём была речь. Я воспринял Ваш комментарий, как необходимость передать какой-то свой самописный экземпляр класса, где так же нужно писать синхронизацию. Поправил сообщение.